# How do you open a GUI when you touch a brick? (with Filtering Enabled)

Tags: user-interface, lua, roblox

I'm trying to make a Shop enclosure when you touch a brick, it'll open the Shop Gui,

Now the main problem is that I do not know how to make the GUI open since using scripts whilst filtering enabled just won't cut it.

Does anyone have a solid explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in order to execute any action when a brick is touched, you will need to use the [`.Touched`](http://robloxdev.com/api-reference/event/BasePart/Touched) attribute of your brick. Your brick has this attribute because it is a data type called a [`Part`](http://robloxdev.com/api-reference/class/Part).

Second of all, I am not sure how you want the GUI to open, but the most basic way is to enable it using the [`.Active`](http://robloxdev.com/api-reference/property/GuiObject/Active) attribute of your GUI element. This will simply make it appear on screen. You GUI element has this attribute because it is a [`GuiObject`](http://robloxdev.com/api-reference/class/GuiObject), whether it be a Frame, TextButton, or whatever else.

The code will look something like this:

```
brick = path.to.part.here
gui = path.to.gui.here

function activateGui() --shorthand for "activateGui = function()"
    gui.Enabled = true
end

brick.Touched:connect(activateGui)
```

Notice that `.Enabled` is a `boolean` (`true` or `false`). Also, notice that `.Touched` is a special object with a `:connect(func)` function. This is because `.Touched` is actually an [`Event`](http://robloxdev.com/api-reference/datatype/RBXScriptSignal). All `Event`s have a special `:connect(func)` function that take an argument of another function `func` which is to be executed when the event occurs. In this case, we asked the brick's `.Touched` event to execute `activateGui` when it occurs.

Also, `.Enabled` is set to `true` by default, so in order for this method to work, make sure you set it to `false` in ROBLOX Studio by unchecking `.Enabled` in the Properties tab for the GUI element. Note that you do not have to do this for every single element of the GUI; if you set `.Enabled` to false on a certain element, all of its children will also automatically be hidden, so you only have to do it on the parent element.

Finally, you **must do this in a `Local Script`**. Because the GUI is unique for every single player, it is actually handled by each player's computer, not the ROBLOX server itself. [`Local Scripts`](http://robloxdev.com/api-reference/class/LocalScript) are scripts that are specifically handled by a player's computer and not the server, so it is *crucial* that you do not try to do this with a regular [`Script`](http://robloxdev.com/api-reference/class/Script), which is handled by the server.

For your information, the above code can be condensed to this if you would like:

```
brick = path.to.part.here
gui = path.to.gui.here

brick.Touched:connect(function()
    gui.Enabled = true
end)
```

This is because you do not have to create a function, name it, and then give that name to `.Touched`; instead, you can just create it right on the spot.